# Changing the connection string during run time

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, runtime, connection-string

This is my first post here, so I am sorry I did anything wrong about it.
I am working on a Visual Basic project started by someone else and my final task right now is to make a panel that allows the user fix the connection string to the SQL database if it is wrong. I made the panel from below, which breaks the current connection string into server name, user, password and database name. I want to make the save button change this setting either in My.Settings. I would be deeply grateful if I could achieve this task, so any help is much appreciated. Also, if there is any other way to change the connection string during runtime it is good as well.
Thanks in advance for any help, have a nice day! 
[the panel I made](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FTKy5.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You need to provide more details about your stack, and provide code samples of what you have already tried. Then we can help you. Are you seriously using vba with mysql? Quite a strange combo! Please detail how you are connecting to the database (give us a code sample), and what versions you are using. Are you developing on windows? Provide as much detail as possible and show us what research you already did.

Comment: I am developing in windows, VS 2015, SQL Server 2014. The connection is made via a connection string I edited in My.Settings folder after I added the database, and I access it like this: `Dim connStr = My.Settings.TSCAN_MDFConnectionString`, where TSCAN_MDFConnectionString = "Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=tScane;Persist Security Info = True;User ID=abstract;Password=****;"

Comment: You probably should look at the connectionstringbuilder.

Comment: What is wrong about the connection string? The connection to the database is good, the problem is I can't change it during run time

Answer (score 0):

In the end I found out how to deal with it, the next code works (posted it in case somebody might need this one day). In order to save the changes, I also had to rebuild the project. So, the code is:

```
 Public Sub btSave_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btSave.Click
    Dim connectionString As String = String.Format("Data Source = " & txtServer.Text & " ; Initial Catalog = " & txtBD.Text &
                                                   " ; Persist Security Info = True; User ID = " & txtUser.Text & " ; Password = " & txtPassword.Text & " ;")
    Dim builder As New SqlClient.SqlConnectionStringBuilder
    builder.DataSource = txtServer.Text
    builder.InitialCatalog = txtBD.Text
    builder.UserID = txtUser.Text
    builder.Password = txtPassword.Text
    Try
        Dim cnn_conn As New SqlClient.SqlConnection
        cnn_conn.ConnectionString = builder.ConnectionString
        If cnn_conn.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then
            cnn_conn.Open()
            Dim config As Configuration = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None)
            config.ConnectionStrings.ConnectionStrings("[name of your connection string]").ConnectionString = builder.ConnectionString
            config.ConnectionStrings.ConnectionStrings("[name of your connection string]").ProviderName = "System.Data.SqlClient"
            config.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified)
            MessageBox.Show("String successfully saved", "Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
    End Try
End Sub

Private Sub btTest_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btTest.Click
    Dim connectionString As String = String.Format("Data Source = " & txtServer.Text & " ; Initial Catalog = " & txtBD.Text &
                                                  " ; Persist Security Info = True; User ID = " & txtUser.Text & " ; Password = " & txtPassword.Text & " ;")
    Dim builder As New SqlClient.SqlConnectionStringBuilder
    builder.DataSource = txtServer.Text
    builder.InitialCatalog = txtBD.Text
    builder.UserID = txtUser.Text
    builder.Password = txtPassword.Text
    Try
        Dim cnn_conn As New SqlClient.SqlConnection
        cnn_conn.ConnectionString = builder.ConnectionString
        If cnn_conn.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then
            cnn_conn.Open()
            MsgBox("Conection set", MsgBoxStyle.Information, "Message")
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: txtServer is the textbox where the name of the server is inserted, txtBD is the textbox for the database name, txtUser for user and txtPassword for password